# Crontab doesn't executed script but, manually it executed. Mac os X

Tags: shell, cron

I have crontab file like this.

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=/Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails-6.0.0.2/bin:/Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@global/bin:/Users/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin:/Users/name/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/name/.rvm/bin
cd ~/Documents/mydirectory/
bash -c 'ls -1t | tail -n +7 | xargs rm -f'
ls -1t | tail -n +7 | xargs rm -f # this is not working either.
```

I want to delete files in the directory if number of files is more than 7.

I set to PATH as well since it's a common gotcha.
If I run the script manually it works.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

My Problem was. `crsutil`

[It should be disabled.](https://www.imore.com/how-turn-system-integrity-protection-macos)